# fish: command substitution issue with interactive command

Tags: shell, interactive, fish, command-substitution

I'm trying to set "[fzf - Fuzzy finder for your shell](http://goo.gl/PeZ82X)" for the [fish shell](http://goo.gl/Gf4S1p). The problem is that interactive commands don't work when I use it in command substitution. Example:

This command works: (echoes all the files in the current dir, and I can interactively select one by fuzzy-finder)

```
ls | fzf
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
echo (ls | fzf)
```

It just immediately returns empty string.

It doesn't work for any interactive command, so if you haven't `fzf`, you can test it with, say, off the top of my head, `chsh`:

This command works: (asks for password)

```
chsh
```

but this one doesn't: (immediately returns empty string)

```
echo (chsh)
```

More, when I try to exit fish, it says that "there are stopped jobs", i.e. interactive command starts and immediately stops.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably just a bug. See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1362 (as discussed on the mailing list)